# How to get rid of these splits on my donut icing?

Tags: objects

So I am new in blender and I was about to do the icing of this donut and I noticed that there are these kind of split openings on the donut (also it looks weird inside) -it’s kinda not really smooth it looks like as there‘d be 2 layers of the icing I would be really grateful for help or advices

[image]

[image]

Comment: A my hello is missing on the top @.@

Comment: perhaps we just see the faces of the object underneath?

Comment: @moonboots a yea I thought that too but on the tutorial which I’m doing this from were non of these (I hope I didn’t misunderstand you)

Comment: maybe he has given a Solidify modifier to his icing?

Comment: A just checked it and yes he did and I just do it too but now it looks even weirder

Comment: make sure that all the normals of your faces are correctly oriented (select all in Edit mode and press Shift N) and also try a negative thickness value in your Solidify (or positive if it was negative)

Comment: if it still doesn't work please share your file: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: Okay thank you so much I’ll try it!